# Base Activity with runnable

Tags: java, android, android-activity

**Intro:** I have made a Base Activity to extend my other activities to. I have overriden several methods with runnables in the function bodies, for example:

```
@Override
    protected void onStop(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                BaseActivity.super.onStop();
            }
        }, Fade.fadeDuration);
    }
```

However, I get a SuperNotCalledException when I try to run the app. If I take the super.onStop() out of the runnable, I get no exception whatsoever.

**Question:** How do I call the super.onStop from a runnable in a base activity without causing a SuperNotCalledException?

**Additional info:** I  am trying to add a fadeoutanimation which only fades out certain views. This takes about 700ms so I need to delay the onStop for 700ms as well. The problem is that this is a hassle to code in every activity. I want to make a base activity so I don't have to worry about the fading in every single activity.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706280/error-android-app-supernotcalledexception) is applicable.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: I am trying to add a fadeoutanimation which only fades out certain views. This takes about 700ms so I need to delay the onStop for 700ms as well.

Comment: You should then add a `fadeOut` function to the activity and do the animation there when done call `finish` on the activity.

Comment: This is what I have been doing. The problem is that this is a hassle to code in every activity. I wanted to make a base activity so I don't have to worry about the fading in every single activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simply delay execution of the `super.onStop` I would use a `CountDownLatch`.

Maybe something like this :

```
private void CountDownLatch latch;
private void long latchWait = 10L; // seconds 
private void TimeUnit latchWaitUnit = SECONDS;

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   try{
       this.latch.await(this.latchWait, this.latchWaitUnit);
   catch(InterruptedException e){
       // Handle
   }finally{
       super.onStop();
   }
}

public void startLatch(long wait){
    this.latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    this.latchWait = wait;
}

public void releaseLatch(){
   this.latch.countDown()
}
```

*I did not test this code.*

Comment: are you sure?? 
       this.latch.await(this.latchWait, this.latchWaitUnit); will run in main thread. won't it?

Comment: @StinePike Yes, you can use it to delay `onStop` from running while you have something running in another thread. What exactly are you trying to do though?

Comment: No I was just worried ,, if it would create ANR crash .. sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @StinePike It probably would cause an ANR, I wouldn't recommend doing it. But what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @StinePike Oops for a second I thought you has asked the question. Anyhow you are right this is a bad idea.

Comment: Blocking the main thread doesn't sound too well to me either. See my other comment above.